# How can I display these cards suits symbols in red and black in the Windows console?

Tags: c, windows, windows-console

I have this array of card suits.

```
char *suits[4] = {"♥","♦","♣","♠"};
```

In order to be able to see them in the Windows console, I have to write:

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
```

Is there a way to set colors for these suits?

Specifically, red for ♥ and ♦, and black for ♣ and ♠.

Comment: Here is documentation for the Windows [console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) with more general information available from the index tree in the left panel.

Comment: What you want to do is to use character *attributes*.

Comment: Windows below 10 does not support colors in `cmd`.

Comment: thanks @WeatherVane . Could you tell me which of these should I use?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how could I find ways to implement it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Windows versions below 10 can indeed display characters in different colours. [Proof](https://privat.rejbrand.se/ahsrunning.png)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand how could I print certain chars in a color and certain chars in another color?

Comment: @Mnkisd: By using the functions described in the link Weather Vane gave you.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I don't know where to begin... it's really new stuff for me

Comment: You want [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) to set the current foreground and background color attributes for text written to the screen buffer using the high-level interface (i.e. `WriteConsole`, `WriteFile`). Or, if Windows 10 is required, you can enable virtual-terminal mode for the screen buffer and use ANSI (VT) sequences. A big benefit there is that 24-bit color is supported with ANSI sequences, as opposed to the limited color palette of the console API. ANSI sequences are also supported by terminals across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Since PowerShell is tagged, you can print these symbols with colors to the console using [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7):

```
$suits = "♥","♦","♣","♠"
Write-Host $($suits[0..1]) -ForegroundColor Red; Write-Host $($suits[2..3]) -ForegroundColor Black
```

Running this in cmd shell, just means calling PowerShell.exe to run this code:

```
powershell.exe -command "$suits = '♥','♦','♣','♠'; Write-Host $($suits[0..1]) -ForegroundColor Red; Write-Host $($suits[2..3]) -ForegroundColor Black"
```

Comment: PowerShell was likely tagged out of confusion. The OP is writing in C, per the tag and the use of `SetConsoleOutputCP`. I updated the tags to change it to "windows-console".

Answer (score 0):

### Try this!

The reason you can't see them is because usually the cmd console does not support the Miscellaneous Symbols (this are special symbols from the Unicode standard). But you can see them if you run the directly in the command prompt. You can try using this code also you can read the _setmode && wprintf documentation here! ‍‍♥

```
// crt_setmodeunicode.c
// This program uses _setmode to change
// stdout to Unicode. Cyrillic and Ideographic
// characters will appear on the console (if
// your console font supports those character sets).

#include <fcntl.h> //file control library
#include <io.h>  //IO parameter   
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); //We're recibing the stdout file descriptor and then we change
                                           //it to the Unicode translation.
    wprintf(L" CLUB: \x2663 \n\n DIAMOND: \x2666 \n\n HEART: \x2665 \n\n SPADES: \x2660\n");
    return 0;
}
```

- _setmode Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019
- wprintf Documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wprintf/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- For Powershell

```
$suits = [char]0x2665,[char]0x2666,[char]0x2663,[char]0x2660;
0..4|% {if ($_ -le 1){ 
    write-host $suits[$_] -ForegroundColor Red –NoNewline;
     } else { write-host $suits[$_] -ForegroundColor Black –NoNewline}}
```

---

[image]

- For cmd

```
powershell -nop -c $suits=[char]0x2665,[char]0x2666,[char]0x2663,[char]0x2660;0..4^|? ^{if ($_ -le 1) ^{write-host $suits[$_] -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline^} else ^{write-host $suits[$_] -ForegroundColor Black -NoNewline^}^}
```